# Is there any meaning to 'first' pseudoclass?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I found this code:

```
$("#some_list li a:first").click();
```

And I can't find any source about 'first' pseudoclass. Have anyone seen something like that ? Does it mean that first element on list is clicked ?

Comment: This is JavaScript, not CSS. That may be why you're having trouble finding any sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> :first is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification

https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

it just selects the first element

```js
$('a:first').css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">one</a>
<a href="http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/5049416f/4/">two</a>
<a href>three</a>
<a>four</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a strictly **CSS** thing, but a **jQuery** selector, for use in your JavaScript.

The `:first` pseudo-class is equivalent to `:eq( 0 )`. It could also be written as `:lt( 1 )`. While this matches only a single element, `:first-child` can match more than one: One for each parent.

See here: https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it means that on first anchor link of li the click event will be triggered

Answer (score 0):

It is a selector for the first `a` inside a `li` inside an element with id `#some_list`:

```
<ul id="some_list">
    <li>
        <a href="#">link</a> <!-- affects this link -->
        <a href="#">link</a>
        <a href="#">link</a>
        <a href="#">link</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">link</a> <!-- affects this link -->
    </li>
</ul>
```